# Where to place HTML5 fix for IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am using this code to make HTML5 tags available to older browsers:

```
<script>
    'header nav aside article footer section'.replace(/\w+/g, function (n) { document.createElement(n) })
</script>
```

Some sources say to place the code in the head section of the HTML document, and some in the body. Which way is correct?

Comment: add code format to description

Comment: I would place any function that I define in the body. The body is meant for functions and routine calls.

Answer (score 0):

This script needs to run before IE tries to style the elements in question to avoid the flash of unstyled content.  Put it at the bottom of the `head` tag.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content and http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing

Answer (score 0):

The most popular way to polyfill this behavior is to use the [HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv). It recommends the following:

> Insert minified distribution shiv in `<head>` element (after or before your CSS):
>
> `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
>      <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
>   <![endif]-->`

I’d recommend this shiv rather than rolling your own, as it is kept up to date with new HTML features, such as the fairly recent `main` element.